# Javascript loop / swap causes one element to reiterate unintentionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I've created a loop that swaps out one element for the next. It seems to work fine except that after each loop sequence (5 seconds), the element marked "1" unintentionally swaps each number all the way up to 5 when I just want it to show "5". I want to display the loop in a delayed waterfall effect, hence the setTimout function.

How can the code be adjusted to show a smooth swapping of elements?

Let's assume that the HTML cannot be modified.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var nuFibClass = ".nu-fib-item-".concat(i);
        var nuFibClassNext = ".nu-fib-item-".concat(i + 1);
        swap(nuFibClass, nuFibClassNext);
      }, i * 500);
    }
  }, 5000);

  function swap(a, b) {
    a = $(a);
    b = $(b);
    var tmp = $("<span>").hide();
    a.before(tmp);
    b.before(a);
    tmp.replaceWith(b);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nu-fib-item-1">1</div>
<div class="nu-fib-item-2">2</div>
<div class="nu-fib-item-3">3</div>
<div class="nu-fib-item-4">4</div>
<div class="nu-fib-item-5">5</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dsm/pen/NePbzj)

Comment: Looks like this question does not allow for a bounty. There is no bounty link ;(